# I would like to rotate yAxes scaleLabel in Angular Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

It's vertical, and I would like it to be horisontal.
There are no maxRotation and minRotation parameters for yAxes, and I don't know how should I rotate it.

I've found a similar question, but I can't seem to use the answear in my code.

Someone suggested under it that

rotation = isLeft ? -0.5 * Math.PI : 0.5 * Math.PI

should do the thing, but I'm not sure where to put it.
Can you please help me?

Here are my chart's options:

```
options = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                      ticks: {
                          callback: function (value) {
                              return numberFormatChanger(value);

                          },

                      },                 
                      scaleLabel: {
                          display: true,
                          labelString: 'My label',
                      }

                  }
                ]
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + numberFormatChanger(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/#7-horizontal-bar-chart)?

Answer (score 0):

They were referring to [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.scale.js#L894) line in the Chart.js source code. You can comment it out to achieve your desired effect.

You can also implement your [own scale](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html) if you like to avoid changing Chart.js source code, but you will have to override the `draw: function(chartArea) {}` function which is quite a lot of library code anyway.